# How to get particular product details among different estimote beacons?

Tags: android, estimote

I'm new to Estimote Becons concept.

The concept is very awesome. I'm interested to know more about this for further development.

I read estimote guide and more documents also, but I'm very confused by  these points.

Suppose, I have 3 beacons in a floor. 1st beacon fixed in Shoe store, 2nd beacons fixed in Cloth store and 3rd beacon fixed in some Toy store. Then, a user enters into that floor and his device founds their 3 beacons in range.

Question #1:

I know that each beacon has only ID so users device get 3 ids from 3 beacons. Based on that ID, how app will estimate beacon's id is related to that particular product?

Question #2:

From Users App, 1st device is in 2meters and 2nd device in 7m and 3rd device in 10m. So, now which beacons information user can get first?

Question #3:

Is programmer responsible for send a notification to the users device based on the distance from beacons?

Can any body clarify my questions? Highly appreciate any responses!

Thank you for your time and valuable solutions

Comment: Many question belong to one question is it ?

Comment: yes, Ofcourse!! Can you give any solution regarding this?